# push an xml file update from server to all client browsers?

Tags: php, xml, ajax, web-applications, html

I'm wondering if it is possible to push an xml file update from server to all client browsers?
Basically my proposed situation is that my server holds an xml file, when a user loads a page that uses said xml file they can request to change it, if the change is allowed (determined by the page client side) then the xml file is updated on the server side. I'm fine up to this point (well, I have plenty of reading to get me to this point). Then I want all pages who are connected to refresh all elements of the page reliant on the xml file with out refreshing the whole page. 
Another words all those pages using the file to update their copy->data if the copy on the server is newer than theirs. Is this possible via a server push, or do I have to constantly poll the server to compare files? (That seems sloppy to me..) And if it is possible, what's the best way to go about it?

Thanks for any points in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a webpage is stateless you cannot push data to it. You need to poll the server for updates. Think about a small ajax script that polls about every 5 minutes, when content is update that script calls something to update the page. You will need a lot of ajax to do this; take jQuery or alike to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, is it possible to poll the server say every few seconds, or is this going to cause to much slow down?

Comment: No you can pull/poll as ofter as you want, the question is rather how usefull it is and if you have enough resources compared to the number of users. If you have just a few users, polling every couple of seconds wont be a problem. But if your users are reading an article; do you want the article to change when they read it? Ergo in the latter case a refresh of 5 minutes would me more appropriate.

Comment: You might want to look at the [long poll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling). Not perfect if you have a lot of concurrent users (a lot of open connections). But instant response on change (if that's important).

Comment: Long polling- this is exactly what the doctor ordered thanks.

Comment: Just a comment for anyone who stumbles on this later- it's very simple best bet is to look for long poll ajax chat examples, really easy to find. But I'm having problems with lag, so am looking into other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You may try an AJAX call to a some php script like:

```
set_time_limit(3600); // one hour or set it as long as your session timeout is
// Keep on repeating this to prevent PHP from stopping the script
while (true)
{
  sleep(5); //5 seconds between polling the server
  //do the updates xml updates
  flush();
  ob_flush();
}
```

The connection will stay open and every 5 seconds xml will be pulled and client updated.

If you don't wont to spend a lot of time and resources by pulling the data if it's not changed, you may use APC, memcache or any other server stored variable which notifies you the XML was changed.

```
if(apc_fetch('xml_updated') == 1)
{
    //do the xml pull
}
```

You may test what happens if you are trying to pull data every second in terms of resources. In my opinion it's best to have a greater delay.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Just a side not, this i not pushing, but pulling. Pushing would be from the server to the client, the server doesnt know its clients (no open socket, nor somebody listening on remote port), so it cannot push. It can only be pulled from server to client, by the client.